# How to use LocalStorage with dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage, dynamic-forms

I have a dynamic form which contains file uploaders, datepickers, select2, ajax cascade dropdowns,... and my elements names in the form are set dynamically on document ready.

For store datepickers format correctly in LocalStorage I use Lockr API wrapper for localStorage but I have problem with file uploaders,select2 ajax cascade dropdowns. For ajax cascade dropdowns, the child dropdown not filled and I think it is beacause of not completed ajax request.

Is there a complete solution for using LocalStorage with dynamic forms like the above?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getDataFromLocalStorage() {

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined" && window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("add") > -1) {
            // if browser support local storage and this is add mode

            var orderLedgerIntId = $(".orderLedgerIntId").val();
            var orderTypeIntIds = $(".orderTypeIntIds").val();
            var name = orderLedgerIntId;
            if (name.trim() === "") {
                var replacedOrderTypeIntIds = orderTypeIntIds.replace(",", "$");
                name = replacedOrderTypeIntIds;
            }

            var islocalStorageExists = false;

            $(".element").each(function () {
                var localStorageItem = Lockr.get(name +
                    "_" +
                    $(this).closest(".dataGroup").find(".elementType").val() +
                    "_" +
                    $(this).attr("name"));
                if (localStorageItem) {
                    if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
                        islocalStorageExists = true;
                        if ($(this).is("select"))
                            $(this).val(localStorageItem).trigger("change");
                        else
                            $(this).val(localStorageItem);
                    }

                }

            });

            if (islocalStorageExists) {
                alert("your order not comlpeted");
            }

        }

    }

    getDataFromLocalStorage();

    $("input,textarea,select").change(function () {

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

            $('[type=text], textarea').each(function () {
                this.defaultValue = this.value;
            });
            $('[type=checkbox], [type=radio]').each(function () {
                this.defaultChecked = this.checked;
            });
            $('select option').each(function () {
                this.defaultSelected = this.selected;
            });

            var orderLedgerIntId = $(".orderLedgerIntId").val();
            var orderTypeIntIds = $(".orderTypeIntIds").val();
            var name = orderLedgerIntId;
            if (name.trim() === "") {
                var replacedOrderTypeIntIds = orderTypeIntIds.replace(",", "$");
                name = replacedOrderTypeIntIds;
            }

            Lockr
                .set(name + "_" + $(this).closest(".dataGroup").find(".elementType").val() + "_" + $(this).attr("name"),
                $(this).val());


        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: which part of your data do you want to store in localStorage? the datepicker? can you create a demo with http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I need to store all elements value in localstorage and I have no problem with datepickers because of Lockr API wrapper for localStorage... 
I have problem with ajax cascade dropdowns and file uploaders,...

Comment: I don't think using localStorage for everything is a very good idea. You can only store key/values as strings. If your user is uploading a large file you want to store that in a database. localStorage is good for saving a few simple things, like remembering the part of your websites a user has visited  or a cart that hasn't been checked out

Comment: My form consist of multi tabs with many fields like datepickers,cascade dropdowns, file uploaders, select2 dropdowns,... and I want to store entered fields by the user so that if the he leaves the form and come back again, not have to enter entered fields again. what do you suggest for that?